# Возможно ли сделать блок с box-shadow внутри блока с overflow: auto, так, чтобы тень по бокам не пропадала?

Tags: css

Пример разметки:

```css
.b1{  
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.b2{
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.text1{
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 #00a;  
  background-color: #0b0;
}
```

```html
<div class="b2" >
  <div class='b1'>
    <div class='text'>
      <div class='text1'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Блок с тенью должен быть шириной как родительский.
Варианты с паддингом, внутренней тенью, тенью у псевдоэлемента не подходят.

Comment: с такой постановкой задачи нельзя, тени нужно место для отображение если у блока ширина родителя то места соответственно нет и тень обрезается свойством overflow

 если вас устроит вариант где тень накладываетсья на родителя тогда вам нужно элемент позиционировать абсолютом поверх родителя

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя.
если у контейнера overflow стоит такой, что контент обрезается (auto, scroll, hidden), то обрезаться/отображаться не полностью будет ВЕСЬ контент, включая тень от блока. Плюс тень от блока не вызывает показа скроллбаров. Кстати, тень от псевдоэлементов внутренних блоков точно так же останется внутри и будет скрыта его границами.

Есть пара выходов:

1. Сделать блок спозиционированным абсолютно, причем относительно родителя блока с overflow: `https://jsfiddle.net/spyqedo7/6/` (если сделать `.b1 {position:relative;}`, обломаетесь.
2. Сделать точно такой же блок, позиционированный абсолютно и лежащий (по z-индексу) ПОД оранжевым, с координатами и габаритами такими же как у зеленого и ч такой же тенью.

Comment: Ответ хорош ровно до момента с "парой выходов" ... без `position: relative;` `position: absolute;` позиционируется относительно `body` и это тот ещё костыль (который больше вызывает проблемы, нежели решает). Второе это вообще костыль уровня "js может все, сейчас покажу".

Comment: Ну,  когда задание инвалид, то ему требуется костыль ;)